# Can anyone spot why i have a nullpointerexception?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I really don't understand why i get a nullpointerexception on this one. Been struggling with this code for hours now and really can't figure it out..

Hope you see anything, and let me know if you need any more code.

```
public void createForest() {
        String name = textField_name.getText();
        String location = textField_location.getText();
        String squaretemp = textField_squaremetre.getText();
        String treesorts = textField_treesorts.getText();
        String pricetemp = textField_price.getText();

        // Convert
        double squaremetre = Double.parseDouble(squaretemp);
        double price = Double.parseDouble(pricetemp);

        forestOwnerCtr.createForest(name, location, squaremetre, treesorts, price);
        forestOwnerCtr.printForestList();
    }
```

My error in console is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at GUI.CreateForest.createForest(CreateForest.java:131)
at GUI.CreateForest$2.actionPerformed(CreateForest.java:104)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6414)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6179)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2084)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4776)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2142)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4618)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4279)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4209)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2128)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2492)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:690)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:687)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

If i System.out.println all of the variables non of them is empty. You think the problem is inside the ForestOwnerCtr? or?

After making breakpoints and ended on this one:

```
forestOwnerCtr.createForest(name, location, squaremetre, treesorts, price);
```

My Controller looks like this

```
public void createForest(String name, String location, double squaremetre, String treesorts, double price) {
    forestCon.createForest(name, location, squaremetre, treesorts, price);
}
```

And this sends us to container that looks like this:

```
public void createForest(String forName, String forLocation, double forSquareMetre, String forNatureOfTrees, double forPrice)
    {
        Forest forestnew = new Forest(forName, forLocation, forSquareMetre, forNatureOfTrees, forPrice);
        forests.add(forestnew);
    }
```

Comment: Almost everything there could throw one. Which line does it happen on?

Comment: Can We get the stacktrace?

Comment: @Obicere Looks like we have to predict the stacktrace :P

Comment: **Read** the stack trace of the exception. It tells you exactly where the exception is thrown.

Comment: @AbhinavKumar my money's on `forestOwnerCtr`.

Comment: 'NullPointerException' Occur When:
**Calling the instance method of a null object.**
**Accessing or modifying the field of a null object.**

So,Your error could be in this line.

'forestOwnerCtr.createForest(name, location, squaremetre, treesorts, price);'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forestOwnerCtr.createForest(name, location, squaremetre, treesorts, price); Please check this line. Something might be wrong with the object instantiation. From what you've posted above , can tell this much.

Comment: what you mean precisely?

Comment: It means you have code that looks like this:

abc.method(); abc is null then abc  has to refer to an object instance in order for you to call methods or access fields on it. E.g., you must assign something to 'abc' (something other than null) like abc = new ABC(); or such.

Comment: in ur case forestOwnerCtr must be assigned something other than null. Hope this helps you. If you find it helpful please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get NPE if any of textField_{name or location or squaremetre or treesorts or price} is null.

In this case you will get NPE when you call getText() on these references.

1. Below lines can also throw NPE if squaretemp or pricetemp is null after calling  getText() method on non null textField_squaremetre & textField_price and getText() returned something for them.

   double squaremetre = Double.parseDouble(squaretemp);
   double price = Double.parseDouble(pricetemp);
2. You can also fall into NumberFormatException is these string are blank.

It will be great if you can debug the code to know where you are getting the NPE.